# problems running CuCumber scripts with FireFox 8.0.1

Tags: firefox, cucumber, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

Until FireFox 3.6 I had no problems running my cucumber scripts. The recent upgrade to 8.0.1 is giving me problems. When starting the browser a prompt is shown in the top asking me if I want to share browser statistics such as load times. I tried to disable this by adding the following to my profile in the .env

```
profile["toolkit.telemetry.prompted"] = "false"
```

The prompt is gone, however my browser stays blank. The setting in the config is changed to false but the datatype has changed from boolean to string. Is there a way to bypass this or set this thing correctly? Downgrading is only a last resort.

Comment: This is really more of a webdriver question since the profile setting is webdriver stuff.

Comment: my understanding is that there were some updates made to webdriver for the latest firefox, have you ensured you have the latest webdriver stuff?

Comment: Just updated my gems and everything works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting it to equal a string value, so it does make sense that the datatype might change when you do it that way.

Have you tried setting it without the quotes?

```
profile["toolkit.telemetry.prompted"] = false
```

Comment: yes, that doesn't change a thing actually. The boolean stays on true which is very strange. If I set
    profile["privacy.popups.usecustom"] = false
This boolean does change to false.